# Windows: How to know if an input device is "Stereo Mix"?

Tags: windows, audio, device, hal

I need to pick out a loopback audio input device named "Stereo Mix" on Windows.

The initial thought would be query-by-name. But on a localized Windows system, the device name would be spelled with the local language, which means that a robust search-by–text approach must support all languages.

To make things worse, [the loopback recording documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/loopback-recording) says:

> Different vendors assign different names to their hardware loopback
>   devices. The following names are examples:
>
> - Stereo Mix
> - Waveout Mix
> - Mixed Output
> - What You Hear
>
> The lack of standardized names might cause users to have difficulty
>   identifying a loopback device in a list of device names.

Instead of this cumbersome approach, what other heuristics could I use to identify such a device?

Comment: This is news to me I've only ever seen Stereo Mix.

Comment: @Shawn It's probably because Realtek hardware is widespread.

Comment: @kakyo Can you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to do?  If you need to capture the mix, I'd suggest using WASAPI and doing it that way rather than relying on the existence of a loopback driver.  They're not so common these days.

Comment: @Brad Good advice. I actually ended up doing it that way, but the problem with WASAPI loopback is that it supports only one sampling rate, namely 48kHz. A hardware loopback supports more sampling rates.

Comment: @kakyo Doesn't the WASAPI loopback support whatever sample rate the system is running at?  Often that's 48 kHz, but not always.  If your primary playback device is set to something else on start, it will go with whatever sample rate that is.  If you need more control than that, perhaps consider licensing a loopback driver.  https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/

Comment: @Brad Good to know about the driver. Thanks. Do you mean that I'd need to set primary device's SR at a different SR for WASAPI to use that? Previously I just did a simple probing and found out that the hardware loopback supports more SRs than WASAPI. But do you mean that I was mislead by the probe output? Is it that if I tweak the playback device SR, then I'd see a different result? But this way the loopback input source would be affected, no? All I need  was to be able to get system output and down/upsampling them at will without affecting the input source to the loopback.

Comment: @kakyo Double check me on this as I haven't poked at the actual API for WASAPI in some years, but it's my understanding that the whole audio system runs at a fixed sample rate for both input and output.  And then if an app or device wants to run at something different, the input/output is resampled.  However, the choosing of that fixed sample rate is based on the hardware and its driver settings.  I've found that with my external mixer, for example, I can set it's clock to 44.1 kHz and the whole system runs at 44.1 kHz now.

Comment: @kakyo I have noticed though that the setting of this sample rate needs to happen early.  (Probably when the Windows Audio service starts, but I've only tested with rebooting.)  Once the audio system is initialized, it stays at that sample rate, presumably to not break apps when audio devices are added/removed.  If the hardware can only run at a certain sample rate, then resampling occurs.  (Actually, I think Windows Audio is always resampling anyway, if I remember correctly.)

Comment: @kakyo In your case, you should do the resampling in your code, I think.  The software you're capturing would otherwise have to be in-sync with the sample rate changes.  If Windows Audio is running at 48 kHz, it doesn't matter if your virtual loopback device is like 192 kHz... the software is still going to output 48 kHz and Windows will resample for the device.  (Unless it's in exclusive mode...)

Comment: @Brad Thanks! I think you explanation is sound. Software resampling is inevitable in my case.